How can I enforce a minimum age constraint and manage related models in Django?
I am working on a Django project where I need to validate a model before saving it, based on values in its related models. I came up with this issue while extracting an app from an project using an old Django version (3.1) to a separate Django 5.1 project, then there error "ValueError: 'Model...' instance needs to have a primary key value before this relationship can be used" raised on all validation classes that used related model data.
For demonstration and simplification purposes, I have a Reservation model that references multiple Guest objects via a foreign key. For the reservation to be valid and be saved, all guests linked to it must be at least 18 years old.
However, none of these records (neither the reservation nor the guests) have been saved to the database yet. I need to perform this validation efficiently and cleanly, preferably in a way that keeps the validation logic separated from the models themselves.
How can I approach this validation scenario? What are the best practices for validating unsaved foreign key relationships in Django?
Here is a simplified version of my setup:
File: models.py
from django.db import models

class Reservation(models.Model):
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    check_out_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Reservation from {self.check_in_date} to {self.check_out_date}"

class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(
        Reservation,
        related_name="guests",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self. Age} years old)"


File: validation.py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_reservation_and_guests(reservation):
    """
    Validate that all guests in the reservation are at least 18 years old.
    """
    for guest in reservation.guests.all():
        if guest.age < 18:
            raise ValidationError("All guests must be at least 18 years old.")

Question:
What is the best way to structure this kind of validation in Django admin? I am open to using custom model methods, form validation, or signals, but I prefer to keep the logic in a separate file for better organization. Are there other approaches I should consider?
Any examples or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Are there guests allowed in the database with an age below 18, or is this only for a reservation?

To fit within my problem, they exist only for a reservation (I know it is not optimal use, since the same person could book the same place multiple times). That's because I need to restrain saving on both models upon rules that combine both parent and child model properties/fields

Please don't change the question after you've already received an answer. Such behaviour is frowned upon on this site.

Can you expand on why the validation is preferable to not happen on the models themselves? This seems like a case where it would in fact be ideal for it to happen on the model(s) (Reservation, specifically).

#AbdulAzizBarkat It kind misses the point to ask if I can't specify further what is my issue. I wasn't changing the meaning but making it more specific toward my real issue. And I added this information within minutes I noticed the first answer wouldnt solve it. It solves the example code issue, but not the title question...
@Vegard My question was edited by removing my main point. It is not just a simple validation. I need to validate values from both models before saving any of them, it worked on older Django but not on later ones.
I guess I will have to create a new question then

I understand that it's a multi-model validation thing, but why can't it happen on the models (or in the manager)? Overload the create() method for instance, create the object with commit=False, write whatever logic is necessary to check the constraints you want, and then either commit it or error out. You'd create the Guest instances first, then the Reservation - and then you do all the multi-model validation on Reservation.

@Danmaxis "I wasn't changing the meaning" your initial question was for validating that guests are at least 18 years old, you got an answer for that and then changed the question to include more conditions. That very much is changing the question. If you had a question like that from the start it's up to you to ask it from the start, doing so after you've received an answer generally results in a rollback like I've done here.

@AbdulAzizBarkat My question from the start reads as "How validate Django Models with Foreign Keys before saving any records?". Now I feel that I must change this title since the answer refers to something else. Rest assure, all gamification points will be delivered and standards will be followed.

@Vegard Your suggestion was what I was expecting: Pinpoint different steps in django requests workflow to make complex validations. My app has a whole validation system build on clean method, and I need to adapt. Thanks

You can add a MinValueValidator [Django-doc]:
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator


class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(18, 'All guests must be at least 18 years old.')
        ]
    )
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(
        Reservation, related_name='guests', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self. Age} years old)"
All ModelForms derived from this model will thus check that the age is at least 18. Since a ModelAdmin uses a ModelForm, these thus also validate this.
In the ModelAdmin, you can then move the Guests to an inline [Django-doc]:
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Guest, Reservation


class GuestInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Guest


class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        GuestInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Reservation, ReservationAdmin)

but I prefer to keep the logic in a separate file for better organization. Are there other approaches I should consider?

A model is the main responsible to ensure the data is valid, so adding validators to the model fields is the probably the best way to do this. All sorts of "products" arising from models like ModelForms, ModelSerializers, ModelAdmins, ModelResources, etc. will then all see the validators and act accordingly.

First, thank you for you detailed answer. That really fits this example problem. My issue is not very far, but perhaps I should been more direct.
My issue is that I have a rule that a combination of strings on parent and child models cant repeat. I will update this question, but please dont delete this one (If you cant answer twice, perhaps add a ----- to add this other approach).

I also have another question for you, would a guest record failing to meet MinValueValidator(...) prevent the Reservation from being saved?

Multi-model validation can (technically) happen in several places:

Model(s)
Form/modelform
View

Models generally validate single-instance values, whereas it might be more usual for forms to validate criteria that span several instances and/or models. Evaluating instance data directly in the view is usually an anti-pattern.
It comes down to use-case and preference. If you need different multi-level validations on the same model(s) in different scenarios, you'd probably do it in the form. If you need the same validation regardless of how/when/etc the model is accessed, it makes a lot of sense to put it on the model.
In the case you describe I would prefer doing it on the model. While you could conceivably achieve the same with forms, the complexity is probably higher due to juggling instances of different models (and their respective forms) inline.
Here's a crude reference implementation:
class Guest(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        from .validation import validate_reservation_and_guests
        validate_reservation_and_guests(self.reservation)

ModelForm calls Model.clean(), and (as other answers also have pointed out) the admin panel uses ModelForm, so this will be sufficient to have the validation triggered.

Techincally that validate_guest_ages should live on the Guest model or at least on a form that is present for both the models. If it's added to the Reservation model that validation will need to be explicitly called after saving stuff.

There's a certain point to what you're saying, but I'm frequently of the philosophy that if a particular piece of logic is desired only by a single actor then it can be beneficial for that actor to also own the logic. In this case - if Reservation is the only relationship where the constraint guest.age >= 18 ought be enforced, it feels slightly more "right" to house that constraint on Reservation. With this setup, you don't have to call the validation manually - but you do have to create the guest instances prior to the reservation instance, and then save in the same order.

"you do have to create the guest instances prior to the reservation instance" and how exactly would you do that given the guest instance is supposed to have a foreign key to the reservation? You can't have a foreign key point to something that doesn't exist yet. The way OP has modeled their relationships a Guest literally belongs to a Reservation, so there's little point in saying that the guest.age >= 18 needs to be enforced only with the Reservation model.

You are quite right, I concede entirely. I'll go back and revise.
